# What prevents the mouse from working for a few seconds after a KVM switch?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse, mouse

I am currently controlling two Vista x64 boxes with a KVM switch.  The switching has worked fine through several OS changes in recent months, including a previous incarnation of two x64 boxes that I have now.  I recently had Windows 7 on one (I'll call it computer A), but went back to Vista.  Since my last reinstall of Vista on computer A, when I switch to it, the mouse doesn't work for about 20 seconds or so (but the keyboard does).  Switching to computer B is no problem, the mouse works immediately.

These computers are running the same OS, one works properly and one doesn't, but they both worked before.  I don't get it.  What would cause this problem?

---

I was going to delete this question, but I see someone has marked it as a favorite.  Interesting.  Anyway, I still don't know what the problem was, but it went away when I put Windows 7 back on computer A.

Answer (score 2):

There are several items in the chain, so you're going to have to do a bit of troubleshooting to find out what's causing it in the first place.

1) Plug the mouse directly into the computer and see how long it takes.  If it goes quickly, then the problem is likely with the KVM switch and/or cables.  If it goes slowly then the problem is likely with the mouse or the computer (software, usb port, etc).

2) Test the kvm by switching the computers - if the problem follows a particular KVM port, then test the KVM or cables further.

3) If the problem seems to stay with that one computer through all the testing, try a different USB port.  Switch hubs, or use a hub if you don't have one in place right now.  Use a powered hub if you are using an unpowered hub right now.

4) Beyond all that, remove the drivers for the mouse from the computer and let it reload them.  Update them with the latest drivers for the mouse if it is a high end mouse.

-Adam

Comment: Strange.  After deleting the mouse and monitor drivers, and letting Windows reinstall them, it worked fine for a few minutes.  Then the problem returned.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is most likely that computer recognising the hub in the KVM and then the mouse.  If you just plug the mouse into that computer directly, how long does it take to become active?

I've found a few KVMs that actually replicate the mouse/keyboard so the computers think they are always attached and switching is immediate.